# Is this boiler noise normal?

Tags: plumbing, hvac

When my boiler runs it makes a loud buzzing sound. I can’t tell if it’s a normal sound. Listen in the video:

[Youtube](https://youtu.be/S4_NZvwd_0s)

Comment: I'd get a qualified service technician in to look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a repair tech replace the gas valve, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a sympathetic vibration. First, use a short stick or hammer handle to push lightly against various parts. See if the noise stops or changes. If the noise seems to come from a length of pipe with fittings, drape a folded heavy towel or dropcloth over the pipe. Does the noise change?